# Why does my QueryOver<T>().RowCount() throw a NonUniqueResultException?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I've mapped an entity to a table and a view by specifying an `entity-name` for the one that's mapped to the view like so:

The mapping to the table:

```
<class name="Foo">
```

The mapping to the view:

```
<class name="Foo" entity-name="LatestFoo">
```

And then I try to do this in my controllers:

```
var latestVersions = Database.QueryOver<Foo>("LatestFoo");
var count = latestVersions.RowCount();
```

But the call to `RowCount()` runs the SQL statements for both the table and the view:

```
2012-12-26 13:30:55,700 [31] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM LatestFoo this_
2012-12-26 13:30:55,705 [31] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM Foo this_
```

Which causes a `NonUniqueResultException` with the message `query did not return a unique result: 2`

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to specify entity-name for the mapping to the table.

Have a look at (scroll to the section - **Some Gotchas**):

http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/mapping/mapping-the-same-class-to-a-view-and-a-table-using-entity-name.html